# User Name in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

How do I know the correct user name (I need to supply to PsExec.exe from another machine) of my own machine. I use windows XP.

user accounts name is correct or the name (\user) I get by right clicking on 
'Start button'|Explore
eg: C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu

Regards
Allan

Comment: your question is better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the username in the User Name column in the Processes tab Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can type this in command line (cmd.exe):

```
echo %username%
```